# Checking if a postgres index is up to date?

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing

Given a table with around 5 million records added per month, this simple query has vastly different run times from the first execution to the 2nd:

```
select count(*) from my_table where recorded_at > '2018-01-24 23:59:59'
```

- First execution: count = 8,756,237 execution time = ~5 minutes
- Second
  execution:  count = 8,756,237 execution time = ~3 seconds

There is an index on the field `recorded_at`.

```
CREATE INDEX my_table__recorded_at ON my_table(recorded_at);
```

Does this difference in execution time indicate that the index is not being updated correctly?

Its the same for other dates:

```
select count(*) from my_table where recorded_at > '2018-02-07 23:59:59'
```

- First execution: count = 6,487,274 execution time = ~4 minutes
- Second execution:  count = 6,487,274 execution time = ~3 seconds

This is running on AWS Aurora postgres with an r4.xlarge instance

Comment: You can check whether the index is being used with `EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE recorded_at > '2018-02-07 23:59:59';` That said, I strongly suspect what you're seeing is the effect of caching the table and/or index. First time it runs, it reads everything in and caches things. Second time, it just has to go to the cache. Finally, unless Aurora is wildly different from postgres proper, indexes always get updated.

Comment: This is a rather typical situation that the first execution of a query is much slower than the next ones. This is due to Postgres and/or file system cache. It is unlikely on this basis to believe that the data is damaged or obsolete in any way.

Comment: Yes,your index is up to date. Next question, please!

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are up to date just after every DML.

You can use:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, verbose, buffers)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE recorded_at > '2018-01-24 23:59:59'
```

to get more information about cache hits, I/O timing.

Also there is the [REINDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html) command if you think, that your index is corrupted.

Maybe the [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgprewarm.html) module  could be interesting.

Comment: Hmmm.... the indexes can be correct, but they can be unbalanced after bulk inserts on many DBMSes.